# How to use Optimized Battery Charging efficiently on M1 MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, big-sur, charging, apple-silicon

I have an M1 MacBook Pro (Big Sur 11.2.3) for about 1 year, but during this time I only saw that the optimized battery charge was activated 5-6 times. Whenever I try to charge, it charges up to 100% unless I unplug it before that. Apple says it learns from my charging habits but it just doesn't seem so. I also tried to use it as when it was activated, but it didn't help.

I couldn't understand how Optimized Battery Charging is activated by itself, so I'm wondering how should I use my MacBook for this system to activate properly. I mean, like when should I connect/disconnect the charger?

The long and the short of this is, Optimized Battery Charging doesn't seem to learn my charging habits and because of that I have to use my MacBook Pro according to its demands.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to worry about optimized battery charging - it is handled automatically.

When Optimized Battery Charging does not activate - that is OK. It means that your computer is charged to 100%. You can use the computer while it is charging, and you can use it when it is not charging.

You do no have to use your computer "according to its demands" - you can just use your computer when you want to.

Comment: 100% This. The OS is there to manage the computer, leaving you free to use it as you need.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But sometimes I plug the charger and forgot to unplug it, which causes the battery to charge up to %100. And this has a negative impact on battery health. That's why I asked, otherwise I'm aware that the OS is there for me to use it the way I want.